# Derivative of a multivariate quadratic

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

What is the derivative of vector transpose?

for example, if I want to minimize function which is written like this $\frac12 x^Tx-b^Tx$ subject to $x\in\Bbb R^n$. What will be the derivative of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is
$$F = \frac12 \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{x}.$$

The total derivative with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$ is given as

$$dF = \frac12 d\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{x}+\frac12 \boldsymbol{x}^Td\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}^Td\boldsymbol{x}$$
$$\implies dF = d\boldsymbol{x}^T\left[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b} \right].$$

A $dF = d\boldsymbol{x}^T\text{grad}F$ comparison yields
$$\text{grad}F = \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}.$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer, the only unclear part for me is the b transpose part how it became b

Comment: $\boldsymbol{b}^Td\boldsymbol{x}$ is a scalar. Hence, we can transpose it $d\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{b}$ to obtain the same scalar. Then factor $d\boldsymbol{x}^T$.

Comment: thanks, now everything is clear